# How to automatically turn off conflicting minor modes when activating a new minor mode?

Tags: minor-mode

I am trying to use a certain minor mode (`inferior-scheme-mode`), which is activated by `M-x run-scheme`. But its key combinations are masked by another competing minor mode (`geiser-mode`).

*How can I configure Emacs to automatically disable the competing/conflicting minor mode when activating the one that I need?*

I tried the following elisp in `init.el` to no avail (I don't know much about elisp):

```
(autoload 'run-scheme "cmuscheme" "Run an inferior Scheme" t)

(defun enable-inf-scheme-mode()
  "Turns on inferior-scheme-mode and turn off conflicting modes (geiser-mode)"
  (geiser-mode 0))
(add-hook 'inferior-scheme-mode-hook 'enable-inf-scheme-mode)
```

However, I can manually disable the conflicting mode using `M-: (geiser-mode 0)`.

Note: `run-scheme` creates a new `inferior-scheme-mode` buffer that hides the original `scheme-mode` buffer (somewhat annoyingly). I wanted to disable the `geiser-mode` on the original `scheme-mode` buffer. I am not sure if this is why the code isn't working.

Comment: Maybe your hook is called before `geiser-mode` is enabled. A quick solution is to write a function to enable `geiser-mode`, but only when your other mode isn't enabled, and use the new function in hooks.

Comment: @Lindydancer Thanks. But I think `geiser-mode` is always enabled somehow in my .init.el. I actually tried to remove geiser, but unsuccessfully. Geiser is always there in `C-h m`, unless I remove my whole scheme lines.

Comment: My suggestion is that you add your "whole scheme lines" to your question. Something may jump out at somebody...

Comment: @NickD I'll try sometime later. Currently, my shceme lines are mixed with a large number of lines with many  other languages (including some that do require `geiser`) and probably spreading multiple files. I also accidentally included `geiser` in another unrelated `.el` file because of copy-and-pasting from online examples. I think this goes against minimal completeness.

Comment: If you needed an excuse to clean up your init file, you now have one :-)

Comment: On the other hand, I am pretty sure `geiser` was on when I invoked `run-scheme`. And if I manually disable it, everything works as if the code in question worked (i.e. the masking of key shortcuts removed.)

Comment: @NickD True, I need to learn Emacs properly some day. Then clean up.

Comment: I think you need toi do them in the opposite order :-)

Comment: The problem with all these hook-based solutions is that you're turning `geiser-mode` off in the wrong buffer.  The REPL side doesn't matter.  It's the buffer containing the original Scheme source file where you want to turn off `geiser-mode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading and re-reading your question a few times, I think I understand what you want.

- You have a Scheme source file open.
- You'd like to start an `inferior-scheme-mode` REPL.

  - It would be nice if this REPL could coexist in the same frame as the original Scheme source file without replacing it.
  - It would be nice if **on the Scheme source file side**, `geiser-mode` is disabled.

With this in mind, let's instruct Emacs very explicitly.

```lisp
(defun run-scheme-without-geiser ()
  "Run scheme-program-name and disable geiser-mode."
  (interactive)
  (split-window-right)
  (geiser-mode -1)
  (windmove-right)
  (run-scheme scheme-program-name))
```

I made an executive decision to keep the source on the left while the REPL is on the right.  We can change that if you don't like that layout.  Load this function, and try doing <kbd>M-x run-scheme-without-geiser</kbd>.  Let me know if that works for you.

PS:  If you want to get more comfortable with [**Elisp**](https://emacsdocs.org/docs/elisp/Emacs-Lisp), I recommend using <kbd>M-x ielm</kbd>.  It'll let you explore Elisp in a comfortable REPL.  Also, become familiar with the following two keybindings and use them a lot to ask Emacs about itself.

- <kbd>C-h f</kbd> - What does this function do?
- <kbd>C-h v</kbd> - What is this variable for?

PPS:  Someone asked me in the past about how to get out of ielm.  Just <kbd>C-x k</kbd> to delete the buffer.  Switching to another buffer with <kbd>C-x b</kbd> is fine too.

Comment: PPPS: `C-c C-d` in IELM will end the IELM session but leave the IELM buffer open.